# why does my cassandra cluster experience latency when restarting a single node?

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I am running a 29 node cluster spread over 4 DC's in EC2, using C* 3.11.1 on Ubuntu, using RF3. Occasionally I have the need to restart nodes in the cluster, but every time I do, I see errors and application (nodejs) timeouts.

I restart a node like this:

`nodetool disablebinary && nodetool disablethrift && nodetool disablegossip && nodetool drain
sudo service cassandra restart`

When I do that, I very often get timeouts and errors like this in my nodejs app:

`Error: Cannot achieve consistency level LOCAL_ONE`

My queries are all pretty much the same, things like: `select * from history where ts > {current_time}` (along with the partition key in the where clause)

The errors and timeouts seem to go away on their own after a while, but it is frustrating because I can't track down what I am doing wrong!

I've tried waiting between steps of shutting down cassandra, and I've tried stopping, waiting, then starting the node. One thing I've noticed is that even after `nodetool drain`ing the node, there are open connections to other nodes in the cluster (ie looking at the output of netstat) until I stop cassandra. I don't see any errors or warnings in the logs.

One other thing I've noticed is that after restarting a node and seeing application latency, I also see that the node I just restarted sees many other nodes in the same DC as being down (ie status 'DN'). However, checking `nodetool status` on those other nodes shows all nodes as up/normal. To me this could kind of explain the problem - node comes back online, thinks it is healthy but many others are not, so it gets traffic from the client application. But then it gets requests for ranges that belong to a node it thinks is down, so it responds with an error. The latency issue seems to start roughly when the node goes down, but persists long (ie 15-20 mins) after it is back online and accepting connections. It seems to go away once the bounced node shows the other nodes in the same DC as up again.

I have not been able to reproduce this locally using `ccm`.

What can I do to prevent this? Is there something else I should be doing to gracefully restart the cluster? It could be something to do with the nodejs driver, but I can't find anything there to try.

Comment: The error is implying that some of your vnodes are not replicated and thus you can't achieve consistency one in the local DC.  What is your replication factor settings?

Comment: Is your cluster fully repaired? And what are your replication settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have been able to resolve the issue by issuing `nodetool disablegossip` as the last step in shutting down. So using this instead of my initial approach at restarting seems to work (note that only the order of `drain` and `disablegossip` have switched):

```
nodetool disablebinary
nodetool disablethrift
nodetool drain
nodetool disablegossip
sudo service cassandra restart
```

While this seems to work, I have no explanation as to why. On the mailing list, someone helpfully pointed out that the `drain` *should* take care of everything that `disablegossip` does, so my hypothesis is that doing the `disablegossip` first causes the `drain` to then have problems which only appear after startup.

Comment: What is your replication setup?  What does nodetool status look like?